# If the coefficient of $x^{50}$ in the expansion of $(1+x)^{1000}+2x(1+x)^{999}+3x^2(1+x)^{998}$........

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation, binomial-coefficients

Problem :

If the coefficient of $x^{50}$ in the expansion of $(1+x)^{1000}+2x(1+x)^{999}+3x^2(1+x)^{998} +\cdots +1001x^{1000}$ is $\lambda$  then the value of $\frac{1952! 50!}{1001!}\lambda$

Please guide how to find the value of $\lambda$ in this will be of great help as I am not getting any clue how to proceed further in this problem , Thanks

Comment: You might start by figuring out what the coefficient of $x^k$ is in $(1+x)^n$. Then ask yourself: which terms have a nonzero $x^{50}$ term.

Comment: Does the question ask for $\frac {1952!50!}{1001!}\lambda$ or  $\frac {952!50!}{1001!}\lambda$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $$\displaystyle S = (1+x)^{1000}+2x(1+x)^{999}+..1000x^{999}(1+x)+1001x^{1000}........(1)\times \frac{x}{(1+x)}$$

So we get $$\frac{x\cdot S}{(1+x)} = x(1+x)^{999}+2x^2(1+x)^{998}+.........+1000x^{1000}+\frac{1001x^{1001}}{1+x}....(2)$$

So we get $$S\left[1-\frac{x}{1+x}\right] = (1+x)^{1000}+\underbrace{\left[x(1+x)^{999}+x^2(1+x)^{998}+......+x^{1000}\right]}_{S'}-\frac{1001x^{1001}}{1+x}$$

Now $$S'=x(1+x)^{999}+x^2(1+x)^{998}+.........+x^{1000}........(1)\times \frac{x}{1+x}$$

So $$\frac{S'\cdot x}{1+x} = x^2(1+x)^{998}+........+\frac{x^{1001}}{1+x}.......(2)$$

So we get $$\frac{S'}{1+x} = x(1+x)^{999}-\frac{x^{1001}}{1+x}\Rightarrow S'= x(1+x)^{1000}-x^{1001}$$

So we get $$\frac{S}{1+x}= (1+x)^{1000}+x(1+x)^{1000}-x^{1001}-\frac{1001x^{1001}}{1+x}$$

So we get $$S=(1+x)^{1002}-x^{1001}(1+x)-1001x^{1001}$$

Now Coefficient of $x^{50}$ in $$(1+x)^{1002}-x^{1001}(1+x)-1001x^{1001}$$ is $$= \binom{1002}{50}$$

Answer (score 3):

You need to find the coefficients at $x^{50}$ in each term of the form $kx^{k-1}(1+x)^{1001-k}$, $k=1,\ldots,1001$.

By binomial expansion, the coefficients are $k \cdot \binom{1001-k}{50-(k-1)} = k   \binom{1001-k}{950}$. If $s<0$, then by convention we will put $\binom{n}{s}=0$.

Now we need to find 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{1001} k   \binom{1001-k}{950} = \sum_{k=1}^{51} k   \binom{1001-k}{950}=\sum_{s=0}^{50} (51-s)   \binom{950+s}{950},$$ and the latter sum should be easy to find.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}
[x^s]\sum_{r=0}^n (r+1)x^r(1+x)^{n-r}&=[x^s]\sum_{r=0}^n(r+1)x^r\sum_{j=0}^{n-r}\binom {n-r}jx^j\\
&=[x^s]\sum_{r=0}^n (r+1) x^r\binom {n-r}{s-r}x^{s-r}\\
&=\sum_{r=0}^n \color{blue}{(r+1)} \binom {n-r}{s-r}\\
&=\sum_{r=0}^n \color{blue}{\sum_{u=0}^r}\binom {n-r}{n-s}\\
&=\sum_{u=0}^n\sum_{r=u}^n \binom {n-r}{n-s}
\color{lightgrey}{=\sum_{u=0}^n\sum_{r'=n-s}^{n-u}\binom {r'}{n-s}}\\
&=\sum_{u=0}^n\binom {n-u+1}{n-s+1}
\color{lightgrey}{=\sum_{u'=0}^{n}\binom {u'+1}{n-s+1}}\\
&=\binom {n+2}{n-s+2}=\binom {n+2}s\\
\text{Put $n=1000,s=50$ :}\qquad\qquad\qquad\\
[x^{50}]\sum_{r=0}^{1000}(r+1)x^r(1+x)^{1000-r}&=\binom {1002}{50}\quad\blacksquare\\
\end{align}$$

---

Alternatively:

$$\begin{align}
&\sum_{r=0}^n(r+1)x^r(1+x)^{n-r}\\
&=\sum_{r=0}^n(r+1)x^r\sum_{j=0}^{n-r}\binom {n-r}jx^j\\
&=\sum_{r=0}^n\sum_{j=0}^{n-r}(r+1)\binom {n-r}{j}x^{r+j}\\
&=\sum_{r=0}^n\sum_{i=r}^n(r+1)\binom {n-r}{i-r}x^i &&(i=r+j)\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^nx^i\sum_{r=0}^i(r+1)\binom{n-r}{n-i} &&(0\le r\le i\le n)\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^nx^i\sum_{r=0}^i\sum_{u=0}^r\binom{n-r}{n-i} \\
&=\sum_{i=0}^nx^i\sum_{u=0}^i\sum_{r=u}^i\binom{n-r}{n-i} 
\color{lightgrey}{=\sum_{i=0}^nx^i\sum_{u=0}^i\sum_{r'=n-i}^{n-u}\binom{r'}{n-i} }&&(0\le u\le r\le i)\;  \color{lightgrey}{(r'=n-r)}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^nx^i\sum_{u'=0}^i\binom {n-u+1}{n-i+1}
\color{lightgrey}{=\sum_{i=0}^nx^i\sum_{u'=n-i}^n\binom {u'+1}{n-i+1}}
&&\color{lightgrey}{(u'=n-u)}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^n x^i\binom {n+2}{n-i+2}\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^n x^i\binom {n+2}i\\
\text{Put $n=1000$}&\text{ and select coefficient of $[x^{50}]$:}\\
&[x^{50}]\sum_{r=0}^{1000}(r+1)x^r(1+x)^{1000-r}\\
&=[x^{50}]\sum_{r=0}^{1000}x^i\binom {1002}i\\
&=\binom{1002}{50}\quad\blacksquare
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $S=(1+x)^{1000}+2x(1+x)^{999}+3x^2(1+x)^{998} + \cdots $.
Then we have
$$xS = x(1+x)^{1000}+2x^2(1+x)^{999}+3x^3(1+x)^{998} + \cdots$$
$$(1+x)S = (1+x)^{1001}+2x(1+x)^{1000}+3x^2(1+x)^{999} + \cdots$$
Subtract these two new equations to generate an equivalent form of $S$:
$$S= (1+x)^{1001}+x(1+x)^{1000}+x^2(1+x)^{999} + \cdots$$
Next, do the exact same thing as done previously to yield
$$xS=x(1+x)^{1001}+x^2(1+x)^{1000}+\cdots$$
$$(1+x)S = (1+x)^{1002}+x(1+x)^{1001}+\cdots$$
Subtracting these results in a teloscoping series.
$$S=(1+x)^{1002}-1002x^{1001}(1+x)+1001x^{1002}$$
We are interested in the coefficient of $x^{50}$ in $(1+x)^{1002}$. This is $1002\choose50$

Comment: The part beginning with *"Next, do the exact same thing as done previously"* either is wrong, or I did not understand you. Notice that $S$ is a polynomial of degree $1000$, so $xS$ has degree $1001$, but the sum $x(1+x)^{1001} + \cdots$ has degree $1002$, so it cannot be equal to $xS$.

Comment: Can you identify an algebraic error in my answer? In what step does the polynomial transformation not look like it is done correctly. If you are relying on the degree of a polynomial, then notice that the first new form of $S$ has degree 1001. Is there anything before that which doesn't seem right?

Comment: Are you maybe using an ambiguous notation? Do you mean to talk about $S_n (x) = (1+x)^n + 2x (1+x)^{n-1} + 3x^2 (1+x)^{n-2} + \cdots$, and then talk about $x S_{1000} (x)$ and, respectively, $x S_{1001} (x)$? Is an explicit index "$n$" missing from your notation?